# Forect layout graph is re-drawing in D3 when meteor db updates

Tags: d3.js, meteor, force-layout

I'm trying to get a force layout graph(like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1748247) in D3 to play nice with a reactive data source (meteor.js). I'm relatively new to both of these worlds, and I'm running into this issue. I've got the force layout working properly, and setting the data source as my meteor collection works great, but when I update or add to the database from the console all the nodes fly around as if just generated. It's as if all the data is being viewed as new, instead of only appending the new data, or transitioning the current nodes to match the update.

I've run through everything I could that discussed D3 and meteor, but my grasp of the concepts is not strong enough here to get any further. Appreciate any help or a point in the right direction.

My template for the d3 area is wrapped in a #constant like so:

```
<template name="ideaspace">
{{#constant}}
 <svg>
</svg>
{{/constant}}   
</template>
```

Then on the client side I've got this. (excuse the terrible code. i'm very far down the rabbit whole here, just trying everything I come across to see if I can get some clue)

```
Template.ideaspace.rendered = function () {  
var self = this;
self.node = self.find("svg");

if(! self.handle) {
    self.handle = Deps.autorun(function () {
//d3 code
var nodes =  DataPoints.find().fetch();
var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(nodes)
      .size([width, height])
      .gravity(.02)
      .charge(0)
      .on("tick", tick)
      ;  
     var svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", '100%')
      .attr("id", 'container')
      .style("top", '30px')
      .style("position", 'fixed')
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")

  svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("fill", "whitesmoke")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
          .on("zoom", function() {
            scale = d3.event.scale;
            if (scale<=1){
              width = $(window).width()/d3.event.scale;
              foci = [{x: '0%', y: 150}, {x: width*1/4, y: 1/2*height}, {x: width*2/4, y: 1/2*height}, {x: width*3/4, y: 1/2*height}];
            }                        
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + 
              ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
          }));    

  var x =
    d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([0, width]);

  var y =
    d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([0, height]);

  var bubble = svg.selectAll(".bubble");

    bubble = bubble.data(nodes,function (party) { return party._id; });
     width = $(window).width();

    bubble.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(+d.emperical); })
      .style("stroke", "grey")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.objectId+"_c"; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
      .call(force.drag);

    bubble.transition().duration(5000);
    force.start();

    function tick(e) {
      bubble
         .each(collide(.5))
         .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })              
  }
function cluster(alpha) {
      var max = {};

      // Find the largest node for each cluster.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        if (!(d.emperical in max) || (d.radius > max[d.emperical].radius)) {
          max[d.emperical] = d;
        }
      });

      return function(d) {
        var node = max[d.emperical],
            l,
            r,
            x,
            y,
            i = -1;

        if (node == d) return;

        x = d.x - node.x;
        y = d.y - node.y;
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        r = d.radius + node.radius;
        if (l != r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          node.x += x;
          node.y += y;
        }
      };
    }
  })
};
```

};

UPDATE: This got adding new data working. Now I guess I need to build in something to check if any other fields have been changed.

```
        self.handle = Deps.autorun(function () {       

        var topicPoints = TopicPoints.find().fetch();   
        var found = true;
        topicPoints.forEach(function (d) {              
            if(nodes.length>0){                             
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i]._id == d._id) {
                    console.log("Found "+ d._id)
                    found = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    found = false
                    console.log("Not Found "+ d._id)
                }
            }
            if(!found){                     
                nodes.push({
                _id:d._id,
                title: d.title,
                radius: d.radius
                });     
            }

            } else {
                nodes = topicPoints;
            }


        });

        render(nodes);

    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are constructing the `nodes` array fresh with `Datapoints.find().fetch()`. This array (probably) lacks the following attributes:

> - index - the zero-based index of the node within the nodes array.
> - x - the x-coordinate of the current node position.
> - y - the y-coordinate of the current node position.
> - px - the x-coordinate of the previous node position.
> - py - the y-coordinate of the previous node position.
> - fixed - a boolean indicating whether node position is locked.
> - weight - the node weight; the number of associated links.

These attributes are not strictly needed for the call to [`force.nodes()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-nodes), but if these are not present in the array, then they would be *randomly* initialised by [`force.start()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start) on the first call. That is what you are witnessing.

Hence, the solution is to reuse an single `nodes` array which is preserved across `rendered` calls. When you have to update the data, merge the array with new data yourself (probably using a set of `party._id` or a clever DB query instead of `.find().fetch()`). This would preserve the old objects which have the aforementioned attributes set now and insert new elements which do not have these attributes. Then the new incoming objects would be randomly placed and assimilated after the call to `force.start()`.

This also allows you to have more flexibility in how to insert the updates. For example, if you want the new objects to always come in from the left corner, during the merge, you can set `x` and `y` to `0` for the new objects.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - this got me going in the right direction. My solution feels very inefficient, though. Would it be better to make it an object? Any ideas on how to more efficiently detect if there are new objects added to the array, or if any of the data has changed?